# What is complement of $S$ in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I have two short questions, and I think they are totally related!

**Question1**: If I take set $S=\{(x,x+y,x+y): x,y∈\mathbb{R}\}$ then $(\mathbb R^3\backslash S)=?$

**My attempt**: $(\mathbb R^3\backslash S)=\mathbb{R^3}-S$

$= \{(x,y,z)∈\mathbb{R^3}: z<y \text{ or }z>y\}$ **is this correct?**

**Question2**:  where can I express $(\mathbb R^3\backslash S)$ as union of two disjoint open sets in $\mathbb{R^3}$?

**My attempt**: yes we can,

$(\mathbb R^3\backslash S)=\{(x,y,z)∈\mathbb{R^3}: z<y \text{ or }z>y\}$

$=\{(x,y,z)∈\mathbb{R^3}: z<y\} ∪ \{(x,y,z)∈\mathbb{R^3}:z>y\}$ **is this is correct?**

Please help me. my attempts are correct or not? and if yes, then in general how can we find complement of set in higher dimensions?

Comment: *Complement*.${}$

Comment: Sir, didn't get you?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi  Andrés meant that the word is complement. A compliment is when I say something nice about you. "You have lovely eyes," is a compliment. The set of points not in the set $X$ is the complement of $X$.

Comment: Oh its typo, extremely sorry. I had done edit.

Comment: What are you not sure about?

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret  sir, questions states it clearly.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret  sir, I didn't sure about my answers (which was given in my attempt)

Comment: Please anyone help me..

Comment: The first step of understanding is coming up with a simpler description of $S$. The second is coming up with a description of what is _not_ in $S$. Then you are practically done.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret sir, that I know. But I didn't able to conclude my attempt are correct or not.

Comment: I don't know, it is good or not, to atthach "our own attempt/solution" with question, Because if I attached it, I don't get replies/answers and if i don't attach it, question get down-voated, really it feels bad :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did exactly the right thing by including your own solution. I'm going to write elements of $S$ as $(s, u, u)$ where $u = s + t$, rather than in terms of $x$ and $y$, because that gives me the freedom to use $x, y, z$ for the first, second, third coordinates. This description is complete, because if I give you $(s, u, u)$, you can recover from it $t = u-s$, so every item of the form $(s, u, u)$ is in your $S$, and every item in $S$ has the form $(s, u, u)$.

As you have observed, any point in $S$ has $y = z$, but $x$ can be anything. Therefore points with $y \ne z$ (and with any $x$-value at all) are *not* in $S$. So your description of the complement of $S$ as the union of those two sets is correct.

Are the two sets disjoint? Clearly yes, for $y > z$ and $y < z$ are incompatible.

Are the two sets *open*? Yes, each is an open half-space. That takes a little proving, but not much. The easiest proof I can see is to consider the map 
$$f: \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^2 : (x, y, z) \mapsto y-z$$.

This map is evidently continuous. But your two sets (let's call them $P$ and $Q$) are simply
$$
P = f^{-1}( (0, \infty) )\\
Q = f^{-1}( (-\infty, 0) )
$$
where by $(0, \infty)$, I mean the open interval consisting of all positive reals. Because the preimage of an open set under a continuous map is always open, your set $P$ is open. A similar argument works for $Q$.

Nice work!

One last thing: you've asked a second question (how can we find the complement of a set in higher dimensions?), which is generally frowned upon, but I'll give a quick answer here anyhow: in general, it's tough. Finding nice mappings between such complements and things we "understand" (like axis-aligned half-spaces, etc.) is often a big challenge. For instance, if you take an arc in 3-space, tie a (loose) knot in it, and then glue the ends together, you get something that topologists call a "knot". The complement of this knot turns out to sometimes be topologically quite complicated, and tools for simply describing knot-complements are themselves nontrivial. And that's for a single arc in 3-dimensions!

Comment: Waiting to see this from hours. I don't have instructor who can check my solution or give me hint. So sometimes I don't even know, where I am going on right track or not. Really, "Thank you so much Sir" for your answer :-)

Comment: "Waiting for hours" is typical on MSE; we may well be on different continents.